# Deep linking of url from email to Android app not working

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to Deeplink the following url into my android app.
  **http://ts.abc.net:1021/abcd/#/login/789**

User will get a mail with the above link . Clicking this link should redirect to app which is not happening though the app is installed on mobile.

Manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:host="ts.abc.net:1021"
                android:scheme="http"
                android:pathPrefix="/abcd"
                />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Activity that recieves intent :

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String action = intent.getAction();
 Uri data = intent.getData();
```

Am I missing something here? Used  [google doc](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) as reference.

Comment: remove port number from host

Comment: @NikunjParadva .Thanks , you really saved my time.  Can u tell me whats im missing in this url?

http://12.10.111.111/#/login/414

 <data android:host="52.40.203.254"
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPrefix="/#"
                    />

Comment: check it out https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing you got your proper solution here